# How to annotate request body to describe examples

Tags: spring, annotations, swagger

I'm struggling with describe the requestBody correctly.
I have this Dto as Request body:

```
public @Data class ContactDto {
@Parameter(description = "Mailadress required if messageType is MAIL")
private String mailAddress;
@Parameter(description = "Phonenumber required if messageType is not MAIL", example = 
"0041791234567")
private String phoneNumber;
@Parameter(description = "Message type which will be used to inform the user", examples = {
        @ExampleObject(name = "SMS", value = "SMS"),
        @ExampleObject(name = "MAIL", value = "MAIL")
})
private MessageType messageType;

}
```

And this in the Controller:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createWichtel(@RequestBody() final WichtelDetailsDto wichtelDetailsDto) 
{
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I'm using Spring with springdoc-openapi-ui

But when I'm opening the swagger-ui, the description above does not show.
What is the error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `@ApiParam`

```
public @Data class ContactDto {
@ApiParam(value = "Mailadress required if messageType is MAIL")
private String mailAddress;
@ApiParam(value = "Phonenumber required if messageType is not MAIL", example = 
"0041791234567")
private String phoneNumber;
@ApiParam(value = "Message type which will be used to inform the user", example = "{(name = \"SMS\", value = \"SMS\")}")
private MessageType messageType;
```

Comment: @ApiParam is not known.
Do I need to add another dependency?